# Does CORS apply to Javascript only? And not HTML anchors?

Tags: html, rest, get, cors

I'm writing a REST API server in C++, not quite *from scratch*, but almost.
I'm using an existing library that handles the networking, and provides a *router*,
but beside that I need to handle the miriad HTTP headers on my own, include for CORS.

For now, let's consider only `GET` requests.

To manually test my GETs in the browser, the REST server also dynamically generates
an HTML page (at routes `/` and `/index.html`) which lists all possible `GET` routes
as HTML anchors:

(`<a href="/path/to/route">GET /path/to/route</a>`)

This is convenient for testing, and works fine.

But then a colleague wrote a React front-end using my APIs, and we ran into CORS issues...
Via some sleuthing and trial-and-error, we got things to work in two separate ways:

1. Via CORS-anywhere in the stack of the React front-end, which includes other API servers. It acted as a *proxy*, between her front-end and my back-end.
2. By my own API server adding some CORS headers when an `Origin` header is present on the `GET` request.

So far, so good. The problem for me is that I couldn't test CORS w/o that front-end, which is part of a large deployment I don't control nor usually work with. We'd rather avoid the CORS-anywhere work-around, since that adds extra network hops, and my REST back-end should be CORS aware and compliant.

Thus I'd like to be able to reproduce the CORS errors we saw on my own. Thus I changed the
code that generates the *manual testing* HTML page to optionally use a different base URL than the default / implicit one of the server that served the HTML. Thus the anchors became:

`<a href="$origin/path/to/route">GET /path/to/route</a>`

Where `$origin` is an argument provided when starting my back-end, e.g. `http://localhost:8888`. The idea being that I start one back-end (w/o an *$origin* arg, but doesn't matter) as the API server, on `http://localhost:8888` for example, and another with the *$origin* arg pointing to the first server (i.e. `http://localhost:8888`), but on a different port, e.g. on `http://localhost:9999`.

I thought this qualified as **cross-origin** (since the port number is part of the origin) and I would see CORS errors. Except I don't...

Thus we come to my questions:

- Is the fact I don't get CORS errors because the GET is done from HTML via an anchor tag?
- And that CORS really only applies to GETs done programmatically (via the Fetch API and client-side Javascript)?

And as a subsidiary question, since that was my original goal:

- How to easily reproduce those CORS errors, in my simple setup described above? (considering this front-end *challenged* C/C++ developer...)

Comment: RTM: [What requests uses CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#what_requests_use_cors) - and the answers are "Yes because they are links", "Yes and fonts and some other bits". "Easy, just call another port on the same server where CORS is not set up"

Comment: OK for the first two answers. That "For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts". I guess the "from scripts" is the part I missed. But regarding your third answer, your "just call" is to write JavaScript to do the GET instead of using an HTML anchor (`<a>`)?

Comment: "How to easily reproduce those CORS errors,": fetch a url that is not the same origin (protocol, host and port) as the page that does the call. That also means calling your server from a file loaded from file system